# Magento 2: What is purpose of StateInterface & when to use?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, state

In **vendor\magento\module-contact\Controller\Index\Post.php**

They are using `\Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation`

```
$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
$this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

When is the purpose, options & when I have to use in my Custom Post form & where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Those functions are set/change the status of In-line translation.

```
public function suspend($status = false)
{
    if ($this->storedStatus === null) {
        $this->storedStatus = $this->isEnabled;
        $this->isEnabled = $status;
    }
}


public function resume($status = true)
{
    $this->isEnabled = !$status ? $status : $this->storedStatus;
    $this->storedStatus = null;
}
```

If the in-line translation is allowed  or is set true `public function isAllowed()` string will translated accordingly.

Comment: It means it only used for Multiple Language?

Comment: Yes, for reference /vendor/magento/framework/Translate/Inline/State.php

Comment: This the part of Language fall back at in-ling translation.